# TestNG nested tests or test steps

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, integration-testing

I'm wondering is it possible to make TestNG show in it's report something like nested tests or test steps.

The thing is that I have pretty big integration test cases and it would be nice if I could decouple it on some steps, say, with something like allure's @Step annotation.

For now the test case is shown as one huge separate entry in intellij IDEA report with a lot of logs which is very difficult to go through and analyze.

[image]

Comment: You can take a look to [testng-extensions](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks). For example when using qaf test step feauture, stpe wise detailed reporting shown in [QAF-dashboard](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use createNode method of ExtentTest class. it will creating node under main test.

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippet or link documentation so I can investigate it further?

Comment: As far as I can see, it creates node in custom report. What I want to do is to provide such a possibility in IDE report, e.g. in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to use Inner TestNG classes but that might be possible and I do believe IntelliJ would render the nested view.   You could make a simple little project to try it out.   There is a guy who seems to have tried inner classes here:  http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/05/13/testng-tutorials-12-how-to-run-inner-testng-class-from-testng-xml/    .  Let me know if it works.   Won't know if IntelliJ renders the nesting until you try.

Bonus:  If that works, would be interesting to execute your TestNG using Gradle testng plugin and see if HTML report also renders the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes can be used to form groups. For one level of nesting the inner classes must be made public.

Try the following:

```
public class foo {
    public class bar1 {
        @Test
        public void test11() {System.out.println("test11");}
        @Test
        public void test12() {System.out.println("test12");}
    }
    public class bar2 {
        @Test
        public void test21() {System.out.println("test21");}
        @Test
        public void test22() {System.out.println("test22");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- JUnit does have @Nested to group them and you can use the shortcut cmd+R etc. to run them, especially if you have lots of test cases
- For TestNG, either split them into different (inner) classes, or use structure view in IntelliJ (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html)
- Right-click all those tests that you want to run

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [`groups` feature of TestNG](https://www.javatpoint.com/testng-groups#:%7E:text=TestNG%20Groups%20allow%20you%20to,group%20within%20a%20specified%20group.) E.g.:

```java
class RecordsAccessorTest {
   @BeforeMethod(groups = "NewRecordGroup")
    public void setUp() {
      // some set up for only new record creation is tested
    }

   @Test(groups = "NewRecordGroup")
   public void testNewRecordCreation_happyPath() {...}

   @Test(groups = "NewRecordGroup")
   public void testNewRecordCreation_errorPath() {...}

   @Test
   public void someOtherTestNotInGroup() {...}
   
}
```